# AbstractMethodError occurred when package private method override

Tags: java, scala, runtime-error, overriding

I noticed that AbstractMethodError occurred when execute the following codes.

```java
package javapkg;

public abstract class JavaClass{
  abstract String foo(int b);

  public String bar(int b){
    return foo(b);
  }
}
```

```scala
package scalapkg

import javapkg._

class ScalaClass extends JavaClass{
  def foo(a:Int) = a.toString
}

object Main extends App{
  println(new ScalaClass().bar(10))
}
```

```
[error] (run-main) java.lang.AbstractMethodError: javapkg.JavaClass.foo(I)Ljava/lang/String;
java.lang.AbstractMethodError: javapkg.JavaClass.foo(I)Ljava/lang/String;
at javapkg.JavaClass.bar(JavaClass.java:7)
at scalapkg.Main$delayedInit$body.apply(ScalaClass.scala:10)
at scala.Function0$class.apply$mcV$sp(Function0.scala:34)
at scala.runtime.AbstractFunction0.apply$mcV$sp(AbstractFunction0.scala:12)
at scala.App$$anonfun$main$1.apply(App.scala:60)
at scala.App$$anonfun$main$1.apply(App.scala:60)
at scala.collection.LinearSeqOptimized$class.foreach(LinearSeqOptimized.scala:59)
at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:76)
at scala.collection.generic.TraversableForwarder$class.foreach(TraversableForwarder.scala:30)
at scala.App$class.main(App.scala:60)
at scalapkg.Main$.main(ScalaClass.scala:9)
at scalapkg.Main.main(ScalaClass.scala)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
java.lang.RuntimeException: Nonzero exit code: 1
at scala.sys.package$.error(package.scala:27)
```

Is this a bug or specification ?

P.S. Scala version 2.9.2 , 2.10.0-M3 and 2.10.0-SNAPSHOT (2.10.0-20120507-163905-843ac9520c) same error occurred

Comment: And I want to know this issue was registered to https://issues.scala-lang.org/ if this is bug.

Answer (score 8):

It's a bit complicated.  It's a bug--the Scala compiler should emit an error--but it's a somewhat subtle one.

The problem is that since you have left `public` off of the abstract method, its visibility is package-private.  If you write this in Java:

```
package javapkgimpl;

public class JavaClassImpl extends javapkg.JavaClass {
  String foo(int b) { return (new java.lang.Integer(b)).toString(); }
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(new JavaClassImpl().bar(10));
  }
}
```

then the Java compiler will complain:

```
JavaClassImpl.java:3: javapkgimpl.JavaClassImpl is not abstract and does not
  override abstract method foo(int) in javapkg.JavaClass
public class JavaClassImpl extends javapkg.JavaClass {
       ^
1 error
```

It clearly is *trying* to override, but it doesn't actually work since it's not in the right package and therefore can't actually access (or override) the original `foo`.  If we change the package to `javapkg`, then everything works.  If we try this Scala instead:

```
package javapkg

class ScalaClass extends JavaClass{
  def foo(a:Int) = a.toString
}

object ScalaClass extends App{
  println(new ScalaClass().bar(10))
}
```

then Scala works fine also.

It is the fault of Scala's compiler that it doesn't notice this mistake--it should emit the same error as the Java compiler (or a more helpful one that actually tells you that the access is screwy!) rather than emitting bytecode that cannot work.

But it's easy to fix: just change the package on the Scala code (or the access modifier in the Java code).

Answer (score 0):

I found same problem. When i set Scala code return type explicitly,it worked.Just like:

```
class ScalaClass extends JavaClass{
  def foo(a:Int):String = a.toString
}
```

Comment: Are you sure it helps in the exact same circumstances?

Comment: Yes. My java interface method return **void**,and scala method code implements java if not  use **Unit** return type，It can be compiled correctly but will report "AbstractMethodError"  at runtime.If the **Unit** modifier is explicitly added, it will run successfully. _English is not good, all depends on Google_